# Typescript Array push deletes sometimes items

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm uploading some Excel files to the server to do something with the data. I'm using xlsx to read and Tabulator to present the uploaded data in the frontend.
This is the loop in which i read the data and push it into an array:

```js
            for (const k of raw) {
                let columns: Column[] = []
                //new Array each loop
                let tmpData: any[] = []

                //read data from Excel files
                const wb = read(await k.file.arrayBuffer(), {
                    sheets: k.type.sheet
                })
                tmpData = utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[k.type.sheet], {
                    range: k.type.row
                })

                //do something with the data of the files
                tmpData.forEach((item, index) => {
                    if (Object.entries(item).length < 2) {
                        data.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
                tmpData.forEach((item) => {
                    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
                        if (key.includes('EMPTY')) {
                            delete item[key]
                        }
                    })
                })

                //seperate the first row to extract columns
                Object.keys(tmpData[0]).forEach((key) => {
                    columns.push(new Column(key, key, 'input', true, 300))
                })
                //create columns Array containing the headers of all files
                columnsObject.push(new ColumnsType(columns, k.type.name))
                //push the data into an Array
                data.push(new TablesType(tmpData, k.type.name))

                //troubleshooting
                data.forEach(item => {
                    console.log(item.vendor)
                })
                console.log('\n ----- \n')
            }
```

This is an example of the output of the troubleshooting where the problem accurs:

```
Ciena

 ----- 

Ciena
PaloAlto

 ----- 

PaloAlto
Infinera

 ----- 

PaloAlto
Infinera
Arista

 -----
```

In the third loop the Ciena object is missing. I tried to do it with a traditional for loop already, but the same issue accured with some constellation of uploaded files.
The data is reading just fine for all files, just the array is throwing it away.

Comment: Why do you say it's `.push()` (which is only supposed to add data) that removes items removes items and not, say, `.splice()` (which is supposed to delete or replace items)? Did you debug this code?

Comment: Please consider editing this code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now that code produces a bunch of compiler and runtime errors unrelated to your question.  If you make it easier for others to see the issue for themselves, then you will be more likely to get a useful answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
            //do something with the data of the files
            tmpData.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (Object.entries(item).length < 2) {
                    data.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
```

Why even write the comment if it is as meaningless as this? What is this supposed to do? Something?!

This is btw. also the place where your mistake most likely lies. You're splicing your `data` array. (Meaning deleting stuff from your data array) This would explain how your data array loses some of it's elements. As I don't know what this part of your code is actually supposed to to, I can't tell you how to fix it, just that this is most likely the origin of your troubles.